How do you persist the Paho MQTT client object in a Redux store?
I am using the Paho MQTT Javascript library in my React App to connect to an MQTT server. Everything is working fine but I would like to provide the user an option to manually disconnect from the server on clicking a button.
Give that the connect const client = new Paho.Client(...) is on one page and the button to call disconnect may be on another page, how can the client object be persisted and used in another page to call client.disconnect()?
I hope my question is clear. Everything else in the code is working as expected. Sharing the Redux code that I feel is relevant and not working as expected (if that is even the right approach).
I tried storing the client object in Redux after setting serializableCheck: false. But the client object is not getting saved in Redux, an empty object ({}) is stored. I am using Redux extensively and it is all working fine but I am not trying to store such an object anywhere else.
Here is the Redux function:
addConnectedMQTTClient: (state, action) => {
  console.warn(action.payload.client); // This is showing the client as expected.
  state.connected_mqtt_clients.push(action.payload.client);

The redux state shows:
"connected_mqtt_clients": [
  {
    "client": {}
  }
]


I am ok with the question edit since that is actually what I wanted. But I had kept it generic to get any solution for a React App for folks not using Redux (and I too would accept any good solution, Redux or otherwise). Also, your second suggestion is non-Redux :-).

Generally speaking you should store only primitives and plain objects in a Redux store. This is what the Serializability Middleware helps ensure, that whatever you are storing is JSON serializable/de-serializable. You can however disable this middleware check and store more complex objects/classes/etc in the store, as you have done. I suspect this client object just doesn't lend itself to being persisted through the Redux store cleanly.
I propose an alternative of storing the data that would be used to construct/reconstruct a Paho MQTT client, e.g. the host, port, path, clientId, etc, that is used to create a new client. You can then select these primitives back out from the store and re-create the client as necessary.
Save the Client arguments to the store:
addConnectedMQTTClient: (state, action) => {
  state.connected_mqtt_clients.push(action.payload.clientArgs);
},

dispatch(addConnectedMQTTClient({
  clientArgs: [host, port, path, clientId],
}));

Select the Client arguments from the store and re-create a client:

Select the arguments and construct in React component:
const { clientArgs } = useSelector(state => state.connected_mqtt_clients[0].client);

const client = React.useMemo(() => {
  return new Paho.Client(...clientArgs);
}, [clientArgs]);


Create a memoized selector function that constructs the client:
import { createSelector } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const selectClient = createSelector(
  [state => state.connected_mqtt_clients[0].client],
  client => {
    return new Paho.Client(...client.clientArgs);
  }
);

const client = useSelector(selectClient);



The solutions are not limited to just the above, I'm sure there are other methods to accomplish this.
Another alternative would be to use a React Context Provider to instantiate and provide a single client to the app.
Basic Example:
import { createContext, useContext } from 'react';

const client = new Paho.Client(....);

const PahoClientContext = createContext();

export const usePahoClient = () => useContext(PahoClientContext);

export const PahoClientProvider = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <PahoClientContext.Provider value={client}>
      {children}
    </PahoClientContext>
  );
};

<PahoClientProvider>
  <App />
</PahoClientProvider>

Then anywhere in the App sub-ReactTree that needs to access the client uses the usePahoClient hook:
const client = usePahoClient();


Thank you Drew,  very helpful suggestions. I tried the first option but this gave me an error Invalid state not connecting or connected.
I still have to try the second option (using the React Context Provider). Will post an update soon.
I tried an approach where in the disconnect function I connect again with the same client id. The MQTT server disconnects the previous client connection with the same id. And then I immediately disconnect the new client connection.
It worked but it seems like a bad solution.

@VikasMujumdar Welcome. I'm admittedly not familiar with Paho or MQTT, so I'm sure there's some extracurricular logic to apply to manage the socket resources. For this reason I suspect the second suggestion would likely be a better fit since it instantiates and shares a single global stable instance reference.

I think so too. That seems to be the recommendation for other similar requirements too. Just need to get that design pattern in my head.
